# Get value from an array

Tags: php, arrays

I have a private message system and I have this function that returns the IDs of all the users in the conversation (except the sender):

```
function findOtherUsersInConversation($conversation_id) {
    $sender = findMessageSenderId($conversation_id);
    $query  = mysql_query("SELECT user_id FROM message_partecipant WHERE conversation_id =   '$conversation_id' AND user_id !=$sender");
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)) {
        $user_id = $row['user_id'];
        print_r($user_id);
    }
}
```

print_r return the Ids (for instance id100 and id 101)like this:

```
100101//which is not what i'm trying to do
```

I have another function that find the username in the database so for each user id I would like to get their usernames in this format:

```
echo usernameFromId($user_id)// this should echo out all the username like this (user a, user b, user c)
```

I think I have to do a foreach loop but I can't think how.

Comment: change the `SELECT user_id` in the fields you want.

Comment: try mysql_fetch_assoc instead of mysql_fetch_array

Comment: Your database would love to run JOINs than getting called several times to fetch each user_id's username.

Comment: Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions to write new code. They are no longer maintained and the community has begun [deprecation process](http://goo.gl/KJveJ). See the *[red box](http://goo.gl/GPmFd)*? Instead you should learn about [prepared statements](http://goo.gl/vn8zQ) and use either [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli). If you can't decide which, [this article](http://goo.gl/3gqF9) will help you. If you pick PDO, [here is good tutorial](http://goo.gl/vFWnC).

Comment: thanks... I will change the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
function findOtherUsersInConversation($conversation_id){
    $sender = findMessageSenderId($conversation_id);
    $query =  mysql_query("SELECT user_id FROM message_partecipant WHERE conversation_id =   '$conversation_id' AND user_id !=$sender");
    $users = array();
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)) {
        $users[] = usernameFromId($row['user_id']); // fetch user name and add it to array
    }
    return implode(', ', $users); // return a string separated by commas
}

findOtherUsersInConversation(10); // conversation id 10
```

Comment: @hakra his statement does not include `i'm trying to build a NEW application`, you cannot impose to just move to PDO or MySQLi. To move to a different programming style could take to long.

Comment: @MihaiIorga i know that but i think we are supposed to also aware the OP that the mysql_* is not safe anymore ..... you guys got good knowledge so there should be more thing

Answer (score 1):

Try like this

```
function findOtherUsersInConversation($conversation_id) {
$sender = findMessageSenderId($conversation_id);
$query  = mysql_query("SELECT user_id FROM message_partecipant WHERE conversation_id =   '$conversation_id' AND user_id !=$sender");
$cnt=0;
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)) {
    $user_id = $row['user_id'];
   if($cnt==0):
       $comma_separated .=$user_id;
   else: 
      $comma_separated .=",".$user_id;
   endif;   
   $cnt++;
}
 return $comma_separated
}

$getID=findOtherUsersInConversation(10); 

$arrayID= explode( ',', $getID);// split string from comma(,)

print_r($arrayID);// print all ID's as you want
```

May this will Help you.

Answer (score 0):

```
function findOtherUsersInConversation($conversation_id){
  $sender = findMessageSenderId($conversation_id);
  $query =  mysql_query("SELECT user_id FROM message_partecipant WHERE conversation_id ='$conversation_id' AND user_id !=$sender");
  $usernameArr = array();
  while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)) {
    $user_id= $row['user_id'];
    array_push($usernameArr, usernameFromId($user_id));
  }

  $comma_separated = implode(",", $usernameArr);

  echo $comma_separated;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to view the array only for your Information try:

```
var_dump($array);
```

otherwise try it in a foreach to output your array:

```
foreach($array as $var){
    echo $var;
}
```